# Regarding stopping of a thread

Tags: java

I have developed a code that will start two threads upon executing

```
public class MyThread1 extends Thread //extend thread class 
{
    // public  synchronized void run()
     //synchronized (this)

     public   void run()
    {//synchronized(this)
        //{
         for(int i=0;i<20;++i) {
             try{
                 Thread.sleep(500);


          System.out.print(i +"\n"+ "..");
             }catch(Exception e)
             {e.printStackTrace();}
          //} 
        }

     }  

 public static void main(String... a) 
 {
     MyThread1 t = new MyThread1();

     Thread x = new Thread(t);

     Thread y = new Thread(t);
     x.start();
     y.start();

     }
```

Now it starts both the threads but what if I want to stop a particular thread, lets say I want to stop Thread Y then How I will do it please advise since stopping  a thread means that it's run method is completed but I want to stop it forcefully how I will do this, please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `interrupt()` the thread. Blocking calls (like `sleep()`) will throw an InterruptedException when the thread is interrupted. If you want to stop as fast as possible while in a tight loop, regularly check is the current thread has been interrupted using the `isInterrupted()` method.

More information about this in the [Java concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

Answer (score 4):

**DISCLAIMER**: this answer has a tutorial character.

**BASIC APPROACH**: we initially keep things simple and do not deal with the interruption during the `Thread.sleep` method. Essentially, you should have an externally settable variable over which the run method checks at every iteration of the loop; then you can set that variable to gracefully terminate the `run()` method. Please note how this idiom can be easily used for languages other than Java.

For example:

```
public class MyThreadedClass extends Thread {

  private volatile boolean completed = false;

  public void setCompleted() {
    this.completed = true;
  }

  public void run()
  {
    while (!completed) {
      // do anything you fashion
    }
  } 

  public static void main(String... args) 
  {
    MyThreadedClass x = new MyThreadedClass();
    MyThreadedClass y = new MyThreadedClass();

    x.start();
    y.start();

    x.setCompleted(); // will complete as soon as the latest iteration finishes

    ...
  }
}
```

**COMMENTS**: The volatile flag tells the compiler that `completed` may (and will) be changed outside the control of the `run()` function, i.e. another thread may change it. Otherwise the iterative check in the loop may be incorrectly optimized according to the sole synchronous behavior of the class.

In your particular `run()` case, we exploit the `for` loop, so our approach translates into the following:

```
public void run()
{
  try {
    for(int i=0;i<20 && !completed;++i) {        
      Thread.sleep(500);
      System.out.print(i +"\n"+ "..");
    } 
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

**COMMENTS**: as it is pretty obvious, you may have to wait up to 500 millis due to the sleep call. But if, in general, your code has to perform operations that alter the state of  variables (in particular, if such variables are shared between multiple threads!), in this way you do not leave those variables in an incorrect state. In practice, you can properly handle a **transaction** since you control the termination. This obviously assumes that, at the end of each iteration of the loop, the variables state is consistent.

Let us now improve on the basic approach to handle interruption during `Thread.sleep`.

**COMPLETE ANSWER**: this answer involves, from the caller side, the use of the `Thread.interrupt()` method, which makes the approach strictly specific to Java.

```
public class MyThreadedClass extends Thread {

  public void run()
  {
    try {
      for(int i=0;i<20 && !this.isInterrupted();++i) {        
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.print(i +"\n"+ "..");
        ...
        // some molassy slow code here, where you may sprinkle isInterrupted()
        // checks and consequent break statements 
      } 
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      // do whatever you need to clean things up
    } catch(Exception e) {
      // handle other exceptions as seen fit
    }
  }

  public static void main(String... args) 
  {
    MyThreadedClass x = new MyThreadedClass();

    x.start();

    // will complete 
    // a) as soon as one isInterrupted() check breaks the loop, or 
    // b) "immediately" during the blocking call to sleep()
    x.interrupt(); 

    ...
  }
}
```

**COMMENTS**: in this case, you already have half of your job done by Thread itself. If you only need to interrupt during the `Thread.sleep` call, then you do not need to do anything other than handling `InterruptedException` to clean up your state, if necessary. If instead you need to interrupt during the "slow" code, you must call `this.isInterrupted()` wherever you prefer (possibly in multiple places) and break the loop; the call inside the loop condition is common but not necessary.

More information can be found in the Java Concurrency [Interrupts tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

Comment: That `completed` field must be marked `volatile` to be guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Luca, thanks a lot could you please embed this logic in my above code and show it.

Comment: Why use an external flag, since every thread already has one: the interrupt status flag? Also, note that this way of doing will cause the thread to stop only after the 500 ms. have elapsed.

Comment: @JBNizet I added a comment to underline that my approach is for graceful interruption. Of course, as already hinted in the code, we must wait for termination of one iteration. On the other hand, we can handle the interruption event and avoid messing up things.

Comment: interruption is also for graceful interruption. You check if the thread is interrupted wherever you like and handle InterruptedException however you like. If a thread never checks the interrupted flag and swallows InterruptedExceptions, it'll continue to run exactly like it would if it didn't check the value of your external flag.

Comment: @Luca , could you also please explain what is happening inside the code just an overview that how the thread x is being stopped forcefully, thanks in advance

Comment: @JBNizet I guess you are right. I think my case serves better as introductory/tutorial-ish, while yours should be accepted if we want to attack the problem in the most general case. You should however provide a code sample, at least to apply to the case of the OP.

Comment: Well, there are plenty of code samples in the tutorial. In the case of the OP's code, all he has to add is `x.interrupt();` to stop thread `x`.

Comment: Made this answer a community one and integrated your approach as the ultimate step in the reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping things as simple as possible.

```
 public class Threads {
    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    System.out.print(i + "\n" + "..");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... a) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread x = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        Thread y = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        x.start();
        y.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        y.interrupt();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        x.interrupt();
    }
}
```